# Data is Null when trying to run basic stored procedure

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures

I created this simple test for reading data from a stored procedure.  I must be overlooking something obvious, because I can't figure out why I'm continuing to get no data.

myReader.HasRows is always true.

I noticed that it is returning the correct number of rows, but I am having trouble getting at any data that might be in the rows.

**Stored Procedure**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[testProc] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @carID uniqueidentifier
AS
BEGIN

SELECT * FROM carTable WHERE carID=@carID

END
```

**VB.Net**

```
Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("testProc", _conn)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("carID", carID)

_conn.Open()

Dim myReader As SqlDataReader

myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

If myReader.HasRows = True Then
    While (myReader.Read())
        If Not IsDBNull(myReader.GetString(0)) Then
            ' do stuff here
        End If
    End While
End If
```

Comment: Does running the query straight into SQL server give you any data?

Comment: Do you have code for a try/catch in place? If not, could you add it and check if there is some kind of exception?

Comment: Yes, I get data on the server when running the sp.

Comment: Would a try catch give me more info than the debugger in VS? I can hover over the myReader object and see info on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MSDN about [`SqlDataReader.GetString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring.aspx) Method method:

> No conversions are performed; therefore, the data retrieved must
>   already be a string.
>
> Call IsDBNull to check for null values before
>   calling this method.

My guess is `IsDBNull.myReader.GetString(0)` returns `False` because `CarId` is not a `String` column (it's `uniqueidentifier`).

Instead, to test is the value is null, try to use the [`SqlDataReader.IsDBNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull.aspx) Method, which apply to any datatype.

```
If Not myReader.IsDBNull(0) Then
```

Comment: Actually I eventually got it working by filling a datatable.  What you say though sounds like it might have been giving me trouble.  thx

Answer (score 1):

First, try running the query in your management studio with the supplied car ID to see what results it is passing back. Secondly I would try to change the if statement as follows and see if you still have issues:

```
If Not myReader.IsDBNull(0) Then
```

Additionally, all subsequent fields that allow NULL values must be checked for IsDBNull before they are used. This may also cause some issues.